# Corrupted file if downloaded multiple times

Tags: python, apache, flask, media, gunicorn

I have a Flask app that is running behind Apache as a reverse proxy, here is the route to the URL to download zip files:

```
@application.route('/files/<path:name>')
def files(name=None):
    if "UPLOAD_DIR" not in os.environ:
        return "upload disabled", httplib.NOT_FOUND
    if ".." in name:
        return "no no", httplib.BAD_REQUEST
    _dir = os.path.dirname(name)
    name = os.path.basename(name)
    path = os.path.join(os.environ['UPLOAD_DIR'], _dir)
    return send_from_directory(path, name, as_attachment=True)
```

If I download a file multiple times, the downloaded zip file will be corrupted, and I can't open it.

My gunicorn config is:

```
gunicorn -b localhost:5000 -t 300 -w 7 --worker-connections 7 application:application
```

Edit: Initially I was having too many corrupted files when I downloaded the same file multiple times, I had one worker, but once I added the 6 others (7 workers in total) things got better but some zip files still corrupted if downloaded multiple times.

Comment: Can you retry this with simple text files (with a few lines of text) and share your results. What are you seeing when you open the downloaded text files?

Comment: As @UGS mentioned, try with text file. If the problem remains with zip files only then try sending passing mimetype argument in `send_from_directory` explicitly